# ordering sequential cancellations of multiple tasks in different actors

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Actors rely on Cancellation Token for cancelling task which can be wrapped in Cancellation Token Source.  When there are chain of actors in this single work flow, the cancellation request can propagate to this chain of actors in work.

Probably each cancel task in each actor can be registered to the token for different work to be done before terminating the unfinished works.

The scenario is such that this chain of works better be terminated in reverse order in such that the latest worker actor spawned, for example sending batch works updating database, better be cancelling its work before its parent actor throw cancellation exception.  At least to me this plan seems safer bet than just throw cancellation exception at the actor very top of this chain of works.

I was thinking somehow registering these cancellation works in reverse order(such as using stack)  such that the very last cancellation delegate registered executes and then followed by the one registered as the second latest and so on.

Using Combine Delegates or Stack with handlers are the considerations, please let me know / correct me to guide me into right direction.

Comment: Can you clarify the use case a bit more? Do you have several actors that calls each other i.e. A -> B -> C and when you receive a cancellation request you need to cancel 'C', then cancel 'B' and then 'A'? If yes then do you need to make sure the 'C' has completed all the work and was canceled?

Comment: Let's assume there is for safer bet such as a database example mentioned above. Cancelling the database transactions will rollback and completion of rollback would be nice be done before killing the thread spawned to instantiate Tasks related to those works.

Comment: If I get everything right you should pass new `CancellationToken` to each actor i.e. A (1) -> B(2) -> C(3). The (1) token is controlled by the client, the (2) is controlled by the A, etc. The ideas is when (1) is cancelled then A triggers (2) and B in turns triggers (3) and awaits the result. The registration on `CancellationToken` activation can be done using [Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.